# Become UIScrollViewDelegate delegate for UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UITableView` instance variable.  I want to be able to register my view controller to be the `UIScrollViewDelegate` for my `UITableViewController`.  I have already tried

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

But when scrolling, my methods

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView            
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

don't get called.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Now `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` !

(I write this answer because many people are going to find this page googling..)

Comment: I don't think is NOW, is just that it is.

Comment: It's NOW maybe because in 2009 UITableViewDelegate didn't conform to UIScrollViewDelegate ;)

Answer (score 7):

`UITableViewDelegate` will implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol also.

Answer (score 5):

This is officially unsupported. `UITableView` and `UIWebView` do not expose their internally managed scrollviews.

You can descend into the subview hierarchy and make undocumented calls, but that's not recommended, as it's officially prohibited and can break under future OS versions if the underlying (undocumented) API changes.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case.  Thanks.

Comment: As santoni's answer below indicates, `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` (this may have changed in an SDK release?), which means that all `UIScrollViewDelegate` messages will get passed to the `UITableView`'s delegate.

Comment: a uitableview is a uiscrollview